# Finding an asymptotic expansion for a transcedental equation

Tags: asymptotics, taylor-expansion, roots

I am new around here and was hoping you will be able to help me with the following.
I have the equation:
$x^3 - 3x^2 +(3-\epsilon ) x + \epsilon = sin(\frac{\pi}{2} x +\frac{\pi \epsilon}{2} ) $ and need to find asymptotic expansions to everyone of its roots.

***My question is: how can I determine the asymptotic expansion of the root satisfying $x(\epsilon ) = ord(1)$ ?***

Obviously, the case $x>>1 $ is not possible , so we are left with the cases $x=ord(1)$ or $ x<<1 $ .
In the second case, it is legitimate to use Maclaurin series of $sin$ and to equate highest order terms. My problem is with the other possiblity, where I cannot use Maclaurin... I know $x=1$ solves this equation when $\epsilon=0$ , but how does this help ?

Hope you will be able to help me

Thanks a lot

Comment: Get a solution (perhaps numerically) for $\epsilon = 0$, and expand around that as a series...

Comment: Well, for $\epsilon=0$ , as I said, I get $x=1 $ and $x=0$ . I know how to deal with the second option, since in this case, I can use Taylor expansion of $sin$ . The problem is that when $x=1$ , I cannot use Taylor expansion around 0, so I have no idea how to find an asymptotic expansion for this case... Will you please help me ? Thanks

Comment: Try making the substitution $x = 1+y$, so now you're interested in $y \approx 0$.  Note that your equation becomes $y^3-\epsilon y+1 = \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}y + \frac{\pi}{2}\epsilon\right)$.

Comment: @AntonioVargas: you are right, but there is a little problem here. By substituting , we get that we must have $y~\epsilon $ . But, after taking $y=Y \epsilon $ and substituting, I get an equation for $Y$ that has no real solution... How can I manage this? Thanks a lot !

Comment: @AntonioVargas : the equation I get for $Y$ is: 
$-Y+ \frac{\pi^2 }{8} Y^2 +\frac{\pi^2 }{4} Y +1 =0 $ which has no real solution...

Comment: Right, and in fact it's true that the roots which approach $x=1$ do so from the complex plane.  (If you plot $y^3-\epsilon y+1 - \cos(\pi y/2 + \pi \epsilon/2)$ for small $\epsilon > 0$ you'll notice that there is no real solution near $y = 0$.)  Here's a plot of the paths that the roots trace in the complex plane as $\epsilon \to 0^+$: http://i.stack.imgur.com/L13RP.png

Comment: @AntonioVargas: so is it true to say that we don't have any asymptotic expansions for this root ? only for $x=0$ ? 

Thanks a lot !!!

Comment: No, that's not true.  There are two complex roots which approach $x = 1$, and it's possible to obtain asymptotic expansions for both of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This is intended to be a comment but the LaTeX would not render there for some reason.)

There are two roots which approach $x = 1$ as $\epsilon \to 0^+$.  If we call them $x_+$ and $x_-$, then the first few terms of their expansions are given by $$\begin{align}x_\pm &= 1 + \left(\frac{4-\pi^2 \pm 2i\sqrt{2\pi^2-4}}{\pi^2}\right)\epsilon \\&\qquad + \frac{1}{\pi^6}\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi^2-2}}\left(2\sqrt{2\pi^2-4}\pm(\pi^2-4)i\right)\epsilon^2 \\&\qquad + O(\epsilon^3).\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot @Antonio Vargas !